# Get reference to the object holding the shapekey

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

So i have researched a lot but found nothing.

When adding drivers you can "use self". I have come so far to understand that "self" is just a reference to the shapekey. But what i want is the reference to the object holding that shapekey.
I esentially want to type "thisObject.location.z" and i want to find "thisObject" by using the shapekey-reference.

So let's say i have an object called "CUBE". Then i add a shapekey to it and also a driver. Now when i go to the driver and check "use self" if i type self it will just give me the reference to the shapekey. I want to kind of reference backwards. In the end the shapekey is just a subclass of "CUBE" so there must be a way to find the "master object".[image]

I mean it is a vague guess i have but usually you should be able to reference backwards if you have the reference to a subclass.

I highly appreciate any helpful comments that can get me closer to the solution of this problem.

Comment: I don't know much about blender's python API so take this with a grain of salt but hopefully I can help a little. You're right about `self` referencing the shapekey, as that will reference whatever the driver is on. Using the `dir()` function on a shapekey in the console, it doesn't look like there's a property pointing back to the object. So I'm not sure the best way to do this. Would it be out of the question to directly reference "thisObject"? That might be a simpler solution. Otherwise you could maybe look into how blender links data blocks together and/or search the objects in the scene?

Comment: For reference, those properties on a shapekey: `['__doc__', '__module__', '__slots__', 'bl_rna', 'data', 'frame', 'interpolation', 'mute', 'name', 'normals_polygon_get', 'normals_split_get', 'normals_vertex_get', 'relative_key', 'rna_type', 'slider_max', 'slider_min', 'value', 'vertex_group']`
And the Blender API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/

Comment: The problem is, that i cannot reference the object itself. Basically i will have thousands of particles that will have the same driver, but each driver has to point to it's own distinct object. It would be insane to change each driver for about 7000 objects.

Comment: It looks like, that you just simply can't get the parent object of a shape key. Maybe they didn't implement a pointer to it in the data structure of a shapekey.

Comment: That certainly would be insane! You said particles, so does that mean you're using blender's particle system? Each particle is an instance of the base object, but not an object itself, which might make this hard to achieve via a driver. I haven't used it yet myself, but it's my understanding that the [Animation Nodes](https://blenderartists.org/t/animation-nodes/622676) add-on gives extra control related to particles, so it might help you achieve what you're looking for? Otherwise if they are actual objects, you could maybe write a python script to set the driver on each one?

Comment: I know that they are instances. What i tried was using a cube as the reference object, put the driver on the cube and then apply the particle system. That way every modifier and shape key and so on would be on each particle. This is why i need to reference the object that holds a certain driver. if i reference the "reference-cube" and then apply the particle system each particle-driver will reference the main cube, but not the object that driver is on. Sorry if that was a little confusing. Maybe i should simply write a script. But i thought there might be a faster way :S Thanks for your help!

Comment: No I think that makes sense. Because they're instances, I'm just not sure how much control you can get over them. Sorry I couldn't help more. Good luck figuring it out though! Sometimes a script is the fastest way in the end. I hope you're able to make it work. Update here if you figure something out?